# packagingExcludes doesn't work

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on a maven project and I need to exclude a dependency from my `war` file. Below are the details of my problem.

I have a project `A` with `war` packaging that depend on

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I would like this project not to be present in final `war`. I can't use

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

because I need the transitive dependency of `artifactB`. I'm trying to exclude the `artifactB` during package phase with the following instruction:

```
 <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/artifactB.jar</packagingExcludes>
```

but when I run `mvn package`, I keep finding the `jar` inside my `war`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be there might be version specified for artifactB & you specified artifactB.jar which is not present. Try using `<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/artifactB*.jar</packagingExcludes>`. I have added * as suffix to artifactB.

Comment: I added <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/artifactB*.jar</packagingExcludes> but still not working

Comment: Why are you using war as a dependency for another project? WAR is a web archive, not a library, so this is a bit strange. Maybe you can move your shared code into a separate jar project instead?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem in the following way:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/artifactB*</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
```

And i also noted I will only see this in the built war's WEB-INF/lib, not in the transient war directory (which includes the excluded jars even if debug says they're to be excluded, which is very confusing when looking at this issue).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
   <configuration>
      <warName>your-war-name</warName>
      <webResources>
         <resource>
            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
            <excludes>
               <exclude>artifactB*.jar</exclude>
            </excludes>
         </resource>
      </webResources>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```